# PHP if/else get_field() with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to give a client some options in the WP backend to customize a carousel that is displayed on their website's homepage. I am using Advanced Custom Fields to handle getting the input from the client. I want to give them two options:

Option #1) Allows the client to insert a string of text to be displayed ('carousel_title_text')

Option #2) Allows the client to upload a logo to be displayed ('carousel_logo')

I want the code to check for title text, and if there is none, display the logo instead. I haven't yet decided what will happen if both fields are empty. Anyway, here is what I've come up with:

```
<?
if( get_field('carousel_title_text') ) { ?>
  <h2 class="promo"><?php the_field('carousel_title_text');?></h2>
<? } elseif( get_field('carousel_logo') ) {
  the_field('carousel_logo');
}
?>
```

The 'carousel_title_text' displays as long as there is an input, but when it's empty and 'carousel_logo' is not, it does not properly output the logo. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better approach?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79349/discussion-on-question-by-marcusnjones-php-if-else-get-field-with-wordpress).

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, your problem is not with the `If/Else` statement but with the logo field. I assume you properly configured this field (`carousel_logo`) as *Image* in ACF.

*Image* fields offer three different *Return Value* possibilities:

[image: Return Values for Image fields]

> **Note:** In some versions of ACF you'll found *Image Object* instead of *Image Array*, but it's conceptually the same.

None of them will show your image properly if you just use `the_field('carousel_logo');` in your template. So, **how do you get your logo?**

If you want the easiest solution, choose ***Image URL*** as *Return Value* for your logo field and print it like that:

```
<?
$title = get_field('carousel_title_text');
$logo = get_field('carousel_logo');

if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h2 class="promo"><?= $title ?></h2>
<?php elseif (!empty($logo)) : ?>
    <img class="logo" src="<?= $logo ?>">
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- No title, no logo -->
<?php endif ?>
```

I've changed a little your code, but basically the key line here is:

```
<img class="logo" src="<?= $logo ?>">
```

This, or the equivalent:

```
<img class="logo" src="<?php echo $logo ?>">
```

should show your image when the title is missing.

---

**Bonus:** If you're handling different thumbnail sizes I'd recommend you to use *Image Array* as *Return Value*. In that case, `$logo` would be an Array containing all information (such as sizes, all thumbnail URLs, captions, etc.)

Use:

```
<img class="logo" src="<?= $logo['sizes']['medium'] ?>">
```

where `'medium'` is your [thumbnail size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes) label to output it.

Also, please check official docs on [ACF's Image](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) field type for more examples and further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You have put else condition on last, that will default text will show if client will not Enter text ot logo.
you will used bellow code.

```
<?php  
 if( get_field('carousel_title_text') ) { ?>
  <h2 class="promo"><?php the_field('carousel_title_text');?></h2>
<?php } elseif( get_field('carousel_logo') ) {
  the_field('carousel_logo');
}else {
  echo " <h2 class="promo"> Default slider title </h2>"
}?>
```

it's default title client indicate to he has not entered slider text

Hope it's work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. This produces a mostly blank screen.

Comment: Try this Dude.

`$field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value);`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php 
 $output = (get_field('carousel_title_text')) ? get_field('carousel_title_text'):get_field('carousel_logo');

 echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's to do with the settings for the logo, which I'm assuming is an image field? In the Wordpress admin there will be a setting under that field called 'Return value' which can be set to either 'Array' or 'URL'.

If this is set to 'Array', you'd need to store that array to a variable and then access its properties in your markup like so:

```
<?php

    if ( get_field('carousel_title_text') ) { ?>
        <h2 class="promo"><?php the_field('carousel_title_text'); ?></h2>
    <?php } else{
        $carousel_logo = get_field('carousel_logo');
        if ( $carousel_logo ) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $carousel_logo['url']; ?>" />
        <?php } else { ?>
            <h2 class="promo">Default slider title </h2>
        <?php }
    }

?>
```

Alternatively, you could set your field to only return the image URL and then access it like so:

```
<?php

    if ( get_field('carousel_title_text' ) { ?>
        <h2 class="promo"><?php the_field('carousel_title_text'); ?></h2>
    <?php } elseif ( $carousel_logo ) { ?>
        <img src="<?php the_field('carousel_logo'); ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h2 class="promo">Default slider title </h2>
    <?php }

?>
```

[ACF's documentation on the Image field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) will provide more info on this.